# Help with a proof envolving a finite group and a specific bijection

Tags: group-theory, divisibility

Let $G$ be a finite group, and let $k>1$ be an integer.
I need to prove that if the mapping $f:G\rightarrow G$, defined by $f(g)=g^k$, is bijection, then $\gcd(k,|G|)=1$.
I almost certain that if there exist such $f$, then $G$ is of prime order, and that will then give the answer (since $k\neq |G|$), I just couldn't find a way to prove it.
Any help would greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is not true that $G$ must have prime order. For example if $|G|$ is odd and $G$ is abelian, the map $f$ defined by $f(g)=g^2$ will always be an automorphism of $G$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p$ be a prime divisor of $k$.

If $p$ divides $|G|$, then by [Cauchy’s theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_theorem_%28group_theory%29)
there is an element $w\in G$ whose order is exactly $p$. Then 
$w^k=e$ and $f(w)=f(e)$, contradicting the injectivity of $f$.

So $p$ does not divide $|G|$, and this must hold for every
prime $p$ dividing $k$. This forces $k$ to be coprime to $|G|$.

Answer (score 0):

Since this $f$ is a bijection, $\mathrm{order}(g)\mathrm{order}(g^k)$. Note that $\mathrm{order}(g^k)=\dfrac{\mathrm{order}(g)}{\gcd(k,|G|)}$. Can you complete the problem now?

Comment: What does $\mathrm{order}(g)\mathrm{order}(g^k)$ mean? did you mean $\mathrm{order}(g)=\mathrm{order}(g^k)$? if so, how does the fact that $f$ is bijection imply that?